# SQL self join - SQL and Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table1

| ID | Code | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TK01 | Yes |
| 2 | OP01 | --- |
| 3 | TK01 | --- |
| 4 | MK02 | Yes |
| 5 | MK02 | --- |

HI Guys,
what SQL query would update **Decision** column if duplicate has been found in **Code** column.

other words :
ID 1 with **Code** TK01 has "Yes" so ID 3 should be updated with "Yes" value in **Decision** column.

Same as ID 5 as it matches Code with ID 4 and ID 4 has "Yes" value in column **Decision**.

I have created that in Access(code below) but how to do it in t-sql or mysql please

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table1 t2
ON t1.Code = t2.Code
SET t1.Decision  = t2.Decision
```

Comment: That is already valid SQL that will work in MSSQL or MySQL. There's nothing in it that is specific to access.

Comment: @Peter That `UPDATE` SQL won't work in SQL Server. SQL Server has a different `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM` syntax for that.

Comment: That syntax is surely going to fail though even in Access, self joing just on *code* is going to duplicate rows for each value of *decision* so it would be arbitrary if both rows are set to 'yes' or '---'

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL I would do this using an *updateable CTE*. Using analytic functions, get the correct value of *decision* and identify *code* with duplicates, then update just those that are duplicates:

```
with u as (
    select *,
      Max(decision) over(partition by code) v, 
      Count(*) over(partition by code) cnt
    from t
)
update u
set decision = v
where cnt > 1 and decision = '---'
```

Answer (score 0):

tsql:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.Decision = 'Yes' FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Code
WHERE t1.Decision <> t2.Decision
```

You can watch expected result without executing it by adding UPDATE statement in block

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT * FROM Table1

UPDATE t1 SET t1.Decision = 1 FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.Code = t2.Code
WHERE t1.Decision <> t2.Decision

SELECT * FROM Table1

ROLLBACK TRAN
```